# Indent each line of a paragraph in Latex?

Tags: latex

I would like to indent some text in Latex to get the following effect:

```
This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is 
a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a
paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.
This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is 
a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a
paragraph. This is a paragraph.
       A Single line statement.
       Another single line statement.
       Another single line statement.
       Another single line statement.
       Another single line statement.
       Another single line statement.
```

To get the above effect, I tried \;, \: etc - but that doesn't do anything. \hspace{} doesn't work at the beginning of a new line; Also I tried playing around with \hangindent etc, but that just indents the first statement. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To indent whole passages, you could wrap it in a minipage and shift the minipage as far to the left as you like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is 
a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a
paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.
This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is 
a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a
paragraph. This is a paragraph.

\hspace*{1cm}%
\begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}%
       A Single line statement.

       Another single line statement.

       Another single line statement.

       Another single line statement.

       Another single line statement.

       Another single line statement.
\end{minipage}%


\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could use the quote environment, this will also shift all lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is 
a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a
paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.
This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is 
a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a
paragraph. This is a paragraph.

\begin{quote}
       A Single line statement.

       Another single line statement.

       Another single line statement.

       Another single line statement.

       Another single line statement.

       Another single line statement.
\end{quote}%


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `minipage` environment solved my problem! I had tried the `parbox` environment—which works quite similarly—but I could not use the environment `verbatim` inside of it. In `minipage` environment the `verbatim` works fine. Thanks! +1.

Answer (score 2):

When you want a new paragraph to begin, you have just to put an empty line:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is  a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is  a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.

A Single line statement.
        
Another single line statement.
          
Another single line statement.

Another single line statement.

Another single line statement.

Another single line statement.

\end{document}
```

If you do not want to insert all those empty lines, use the `\par` command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is 
a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a
paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.
This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is 
a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a
paragraph. This is a paragraph.\par A Single line statement. \par
Another single line statement.\par       
Another single line statement.\par 
Another single line statement.\par 
Another single line statement.\par 
Another single line statement.\par 

\end{document}
```

In case you need further information or you want to modify the basic setting, have a look [here](https://it.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Paragraphs_and_new_lines) and/or [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting).